# Debian Installer Partman and reserved blocks

Tags: debian, storage, lvm, partition

I did this preseed configuration but I'm unable to remove the percentage of reserved blocks directly from the partman recipe. It seems that the option "partman-basicfilesystems/specify_reserved" is designed for it but it doesn't work.

Here is my preseed for partitioning :

```
d-i partman-auto/method string lvm
d-i partman-auto/choose_recipe select myrecipe

d-i partman-lvm/device_remove_lvm boolean true
d-i partman-md/device_remove_md boolean true

d-i partman-basicfilesystems/specify_reserved string 0

d-i partman-auto-lvm/new_vg_name string vg

d-i partman-auto/expert_recipe string \
    myrecipe :: \
        256 300 256 ext3 \
            $primary{ } $lvmignore{ } $bootable{ } \
            method{ format } format{ } \
            use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext3 } mountpoint{ /boot } . \
        50000 10000 50000 ext4 \
            $defaultignore{ } $lvmok{ } \
            method{ lvm } format{ } \
            lv_name{ root } \
            use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 } mountpoint{ / } . \
        8000 10000 8000 linux-swap \
            $defaultignore{ } $lvmok{ } \
            method{ swap } format{ } \
            lv_name{ swap } . \
        20 1000 1000000000 ext4 \
            $defaultignore{ } $lvmok{ } \
            method{ lvm } format{ } \
            lv_name{ home } \
            use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 } mountpoint{ /home } .
```

Once install is done if I check reserved blocks :

```
root@host:~# tune2fs -l /dev/mapper/vg-root | grep Reserved
Reserved block count:     610304
Reserved GDT blocks:      1021
Reserved blocks uid:      0 (user root)
Reserved blocks gid:      0 (group root)

root@lsibox:~# tune2fs -l /dev/mapper/vg-home | grep Reserved
Reserved block count:     340582
Reserved GDT blocks:      1022
Reserved blocks uid:      0 (user root)
Reserved blocks gid:      0 (group root)
```

Am I missing something with Partman or should I just do it postinstall with tune2fs ? Since it is possible to remove it during a manual install I believe there is a Partman/debian installer answer to this !

Answer (score 1):

I found the right parameter "reserved_for_root{ 0 }"

```
50000 10000 50000 ext4 \
                        $defaultignore{ } $lvmok{ } \
                        method{ lvm } format{ } \
                        lv_name{ root } \
                        use_filesystem{ } reserved_for_root{ 0 } filesystem{ ext4 } mountpoint{ / }
```